# ¿How can I create a multi input, customized terminal forms like FoxPlus, Clipper, dBaseIII+?

Tags: command-line, bash, programming

In the past we had tools like clipper, FoxPlus or the ancient dBaseIII+/dBaseIV to create multi input forms in which we were able to put things almost anywhere in the reduced available space (25 lines x 80 cols).

[image: Source: https://psychocod3r.wordpress.com/2020/07/21/exploring-borland-dbase-iv-for-dos/]

*Source: https://psychocod3r.wordpress.com/2020/07/21/exploring-borland-dbase-iv-for-dos/*

I have, in example, seen the old systems at AutoZone stores where you get a form drawn on the screen, and the user can navigate through the fields before running an action.

[image: AutoZone]

*Source: https://fr.yelp.ca/biz/autozone-auto-parts-hialeah-5?page_src=related_bizes*

Another example is:

[image]

*Source: http://keyhut.com/pos.htm*

**¿Is it there a similar tool for bash?**

I am aware of the dialog command, which provides customizable single-column multi input forms, but what I expect is the ability to tell where in the screen the labels and textboxes are going to appear.

[image]

Comment: Why all the dbase/foxbase off-topic stuff?  Why not just mention `curses` (etc) that predate dbase III anyway? or use tools like `zenity` ?

Comment: @guiverc it is easy to talk about something you know. The learning process makes people to ask for what they may wish to learn. Did you know that? Thank you for pointing me to `curses`. But I will follow up useful answers only. Regards

Comment: FYI:  `curses` was replaced by `ncurses` (new curses) which is the accepted answer

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The [ncurses programming library](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ncurses) is what you are looking for. This is the library, dating back to 1993, that allows you to create text-based user interfaces that should run on any posix terminal.

Comment: Thank you very much. I am going to follow up your useful answer and start learning new things from this. Regards